# Json_decode not presenting correctly

Tags: php, json

Hi I've been trying to work this out all day.

for some reason if I load JSON remotely it correctly decodes using the following;

```
$uri = 'http://example.com/json
$data = file_get_contents($uri); 
$json = json_decode($data);
```

but if I do try to load the json from a varibl it doesn't work print_r() just  gives me nothing, I've tried;

```
$attch = '{"url": "https://example.com/messages/AgEFFo5ZtHR8rorLtJhMdpu9FKM_X11wZA==/attachments/0", "content-type": "application/pdf", "name": "20201181000954.pdf", "size": 18419}';


$jsn = json_decode($attch, true);
        
$url = $jsn[0]->url;
$size = $jsn[0]->size;
$name = $jsn[0]->name;
$content_type = $jsn[0]->content-type;


print($url);
print_r($size);
print_r($name);

echo 'testing';
```

and

```
$attch = '{"url": "https://example.com/messages/AgEFFo5ZtHR8rorLtJhMdpu9FKM_X11wZA==/attachments/0", "content-type": "application/pdf", "name": "20201181000954.pdf", "size": 18419}';


$jsn = json_decode($attch, true);
        
$url = $jsn->url;
$size = $jsn->size;
$name = $jsn->name;
$content_type = $jsn->content-type;


print_r($url);
print_r($size);
print_r($name);

echo 'testing';
```

I've only got  `echo 'testing';` so I could let easily if the page actually loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You json is getting array format not in object. You can't access as object.

Output of

```
var_dump($jsn);
print_r($jsn);
```

```
array(4) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(79) "https://example.com/messages/AgEFFo5ZtHR8rorLtJhMdpu9FKM_X11wZA==/attachments/0"
  ["content-type"]=>
  string(15) "application/pdf"
  ["name"]=>
  string(18) "20201181000954.pdf"
  ["size"]=>
  int(18419)
}
```

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://example.com/messages/AgEFFo5ZtHR8rorLtJhMdpu9FKM_X11wZA==/attachments/0
    [content-type] => application/pdf
    [name] => 20201181000954.pdf
    [size] => 18419
)
```

You have to access value using

```
$jsn['url'];
```

Code:

```php
<?php
// Your code here!
$attch = '{"url": "https://example.com/messages/AgEFFo5ZtHR8rorLtJhMdpu9FKM_X11wZA==/attachments/0", "content-type": "application/pdf", "name": "20201181000954.pdf", "size": 18419}';


$jsn = json_decode($attch, true);
        
//var_dump($jsn);
print_r($jsn);
 
$url = $jsn["url"];
$size = $jsn["size"];
$name = $jsn["name"];
$content_type = $jsn["content-type"];


echo $url."\n";
echo $size."\n";
echo $name."\n";
echo $content_type."\n";

?>
```

Comment: if this answer help you don't forget to accept as answer. @jamesL

Comment: I'm afraid all this gives me is a blank screen the same as my code if I add an check echo of  `echo 'testing';` then all that's displayed is "testing"

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you cannot use the following line

`$content_type = $json->content-type`

as it is not valid. Variables and object properties should ideally be camelCase or StudlyCase or snake_case, depending on preference, but don't try to use kebab-case as it will cause issues.

The issue otherwise is that `json_decode()` has 2 arguments, the second one is to return an associative array rather than an object (StdClass).

Simply change `json_decode($attch, true)` to `json_decode($attch)` and observe what I mentioned about your variable names, if content-type is the key and cannot be changed, leave `json_decode($attch, true)` as it is, and access the results with `$jsn['key']` example `$json['content-type']`